# How to sleep() and release monitors temporary?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, wait

I need to sleep for a given amount of time and release monitors for that time. How to accomplish that? May be wait for some timer or something?

**UPDATE**

I am implementing sound processing and need to delay stream read/write if is very advanced in time. I think there are two general approaches: (1) wait when big advance (2) have special monitor and timer to lock it until time come.

Comment: What do you mean by "monitors"?  You may be looking for Java's `wait` and `notify` framework [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wait() but that releases only one monitor, not monitors.

From your question it suggest a number of design issues.  Ideally you

- shouldn't be locking multiple monitors at once.
- shouldn't be using wait/notify, use the concurrency library instead.
- shouldn't be waiting an arbitrary amount of time.
- shouldn't be releasing a lock temporarily.  You can use other models to avoid needing to do this. e.g. the actor model.

Comment: So how to implement sound data pipe? Writer should not write very fast, it should wait if trying to write in big advance, but the wait should be measured.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this feature is currently available. Reason being

1)Once your thread releases the lock you cannot guarantee that after the elapsed time (say x secs) you will get the lock back for sure. The JVM itself is not designed this way.

2)The Wait() method is overloaded to accept time in millisecs but the implementation only makes sure that lock is released as soon as wait is called.It doesn't guarantee that you will get back the lock after elapsed time.

why would you need such a feature? I assume you must be doing something which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Method sleep() doesn't need acquire lock ,so what do you want to release?How do you lock the monitors?

Comment: I am locking monitors with `synchronized`, as usual.